# How can i find the string inside single quotes in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the string inside these lines

```
key: value
key: 'value'
```

I am using this regex

`re.compile(r"(.*key: )(.*)")`

but \2 always catches single quotes as well.

I tried many things like

`(.*key: )'?(.*)'?` but didn't work

I am trying like this

```
line = regex.sub(r"\1'blah'\2", line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to capture the value which was not present within the single quotes aswell as the one present within the single quotes.

```
key:\s*'?([^'\n]*)'?
```

Group index 1 contains the value of the field `key`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bX3wF8/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """key: value
... key: 'value'"""
>>> m = re.findall(r"key:\s*'?([^'\n]*)'?", s, re.M)
>>> m
['value', 'value']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s1 = "key: value"
s2 = "key: 'value'"

line = re.search(r'.*key: \'?(.*?)(\'?)$', s1)
print line.group(1) # prints value

line = re.search(r'.*key: \'?(.*?)(\'?)$', s2)
print line.group(1) # prints value
```